# Is there an ANN vector-search index that supports incremental ingestion and deletion of elements?

Tags: search, embeddings, k-nearest-neighbors

I have looked at a few libraries for ANN search of high dimensional vectors. Although impressive, they come with a huge baggage of fine print. Many of them only support ingesting the vectors in one shot. there is no support for deleting elements from the index. There are a ton of hyperparameters that need to be tuned etc. Is there any index that supports following requirements:

- I should be able to add vectors incrementally to the index just like I can do with conventional databases. I will not be having my entire dataset available in advance.
- I don't know how many vectors I will be adding. Could be 1000 or could be 1B. I need an index that auto-scales as I add vectors to it. RAM limitation is okay i.e., assume infinite RAM is available for now (bonus if it can handle datasets that cannot fit in RAM).
- I don't know how many nearest neighbors I will be querying for at time of building the index. Could be 5 or could be 100. The build step should not ask me to declare in advance the number of NN I will be querying for (looks like ScaNN algorithm asks for this).
- I should be able to delete elements from the index. It should be a real deletion leading to freeing up of memory, not marking element with a tombstone.
- I don't want to be tuning dozens of hyperparamaters. I can tell the index the length of my embedding. It should derive hyperparameters from it and change them as the index size grows etc.
- It should have Python bindings. however, willing to compromise on this somewhat. I can add the bindings myself.

Of course, there are price-performance tradeoffs in these scenarios. It goes without saying that I am not looking for brute-force algorithms and other trivial solutions. I am willing to pay a reasonable price in terms of performance as long as above requirements are met. What is reasonable? lets say I am willing to settle for half of the QPS than what the [top-performing algorithm](https://ann-benchmarks.com) gives but falls short on requirements above.